# How do I get individual mongo server status from mongo template in spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I am writing some code to periodically check db connectivity and find status of each individual member of the mongo replica set.

I want the result of the following mongo command to be accessed through spring boot's mongo template.

`db.adminCommand({replSetGetStatus: 1})`

When I try to access this from mongo template I am getting unauthorized error:

```
Bson ping = new BasicDBObject("replSetGetStatus", "1");
String test = mongoTemplate.getDb().runCommand(ping).toString();
```

```
Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'replSetGetStatus may only be run against the admin database.'
```

Is there any other way to achieve what I am looking for? Thanks

Comment: What database context ('namespace') are you running the command against? The error suggests that it currently isn't `admin`, and that adjusting that would resolve the problem. Note also that `adminCommand()` is a special form of the `runCommand()` function that automatically routes the command to the `admin` database regardless of what context is currently set in the shell

Comment: `not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: \"1\", $db: \"admin\", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1694076477, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 8483708B704532E3D90E8E986C60262553B18A79), keyId: 7231366454078078978 } }, lsid: { id: UUID(\"4c1f1d45-a000-40c6-a212-b86a5b5873c2\") }`  as you see here it is the admin database I am running it against

Comment: Have you authenticated with a user who has appropriate privileges to run the command?

Comment: Yup, I used the same db / user to query the command directly against the mongo db and it works. Just is not working through the code